# WPF. Change Background color TextBlock if text in TextBlock is equal text in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have Combobox with DeviceName. And I have TextBlock with text in DataGrid from DB

```
<DataGrid>
...
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Device" Width="230">
...
    <Border BorderBrush="#FF757576" BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 1">
        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelDevice" Orientation="Horizontal" >                                                
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=DeviceName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200"/>
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Count}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="30" />
        </StackPanel>
   </Border>
...
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

How to Change Background color TextBlock if text in TextBlock is equal text in ComboBox
When i choose text in ComboBox, I filtered collection and add it to Datagrid. I want to change color TextBlock if text in TextBlock = text in ComboBox
[image]

Comment: This question may lead to a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: what do you want to actually achieve? highlight the current selected row in the datagrid?

Comment: There is no _combobox_ in your code. But anyway you can use relative source binding to bind foreground colors of textblock and combobox

Comment: @Mat When i choose text in ComboBox, I filtered collection and add it to Datagrid. I want to change color TextBlock if text in TextBlock = text in ComboBox. I could not bind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it so way:

```
<Border BorderBrush="#FF757576" BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 1">
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelDevice" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=DeviceName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" >
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>                                                               
                        <DataTrigger Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiValueEqualityConverter}">
                                    <Binding  ElementName="ComboBoxModels" Path="SelectedValue"/>
                                    <Binding  Path="DeviceName"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </DataTrigger.Binding>
                       <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Red"/>
                   </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
       </TextBlock.Style>      
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Count}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="30" />
  </StackPanel>
 </Border>
```

[image]